# Saving the user input as variable in c# windows form

Tags: c#, variables, folderbrowserdialog

So far if a user inputs something, I store in a label property. I know this can't be right. How can I update a variable based on user input for use across whichever event needs to use it?

This is one of many things I've tried. I can't even figure out the right search terms to google the solution for what I need to do.

```
namespace Words
{
  public partial class formWords : Form
  {
    int x = 5;
    int y = 50;
    int buttonWidth = 120;
    int buttonHeight = 40;
    string fileList = "";
    string word = "";
    string wordFolderPath = @"C:\words\";// this is the variable I want to change with the dialog box below.

  private void selectWordFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (folder.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string folderPath = folder.SelectedPath;
            formWords.wordFolderPath = folderPath;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wordFolderPath` is a variable public to your class (but private outside of it). This means that anything inside your class can freely read/write the value.

As for your syntax, you can just use the variable name or use `this.`:

```
private void DoAThing()
{
    wordFolderPath = "asdf";
    this.wordFolderPath = "qwerty"; //these are the same
}
```

You can't use the current class's name when accessing an internal variable. `formWords` is a type, not an instance.

The only advantage of using `this` is because it is legal to have a variable of the same name defined within your method. Using this keyword makes sure you are talking about the class's member.

Comment: I thought it was far more complicated than it was. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just changing `formWords.wordFolderPath = folderPath;`

to `wordFolderPath = folderPath;`

or `this.wordFolderPath = folderPath;`

should fix your problem

Also, there should have been a compiler error in the error list saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property..."

If you don't have your error list visible you should definitely turn it on.